# Stop ability to post to Asp.Net WebForm Page externally

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms, csrf

In our system we use ASP.Net WebForms pages.

We have a self registration web page in our system where a user can come along and register to start using our system.

We have recently discovered that one of our clients are posting form data to that page from their website which in turn submits the form on the page.

We want to stop this from happening. We don't mind if they embed the page into an `IFrame` because it won't work correctly anyway. But we need to stop them from posting form data to that page from their system / website.

Is there an attribute that we can set or something which stop external posting to that page? Or perhaps an other alternative, Ajax seems to jump to mind?

Not quote sure what to search for, did a quick search online but couldn't find anything.

**Reason for wanting to Prevent this:**

When something goes wrong on that page, the user trying to register does not get any error messages back from our system so we are getting a ton of support about this. Surely we can add functionality to support but we would rather not. Also want to prevent bot attacks on that page because each submit will create a user if they do not exist.

Comment: Are you able to just add a captcha sort of functionality to your registration page? I don't think there's a ton you can do to prevent a script from automatically filling in a username and password field and submitting register, beyond requiring Authentication emails being sent out / clicked and or captchas.

Comment: I guess the obvious question is... *why* do you necessarily need to prevent this?  (That is, you may be trying to solve a non-existent problem or trying to solve the wrong problem.)  Adding something like a CAPTCHA to your page should at least make it prohibitively difficult for them to do this, so that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft added built-in CSRF protection to new web forms application projects. To utilize this code, add a new ASP .NET Web Forms Application to your solution and view the Site.Master code behind page. This solution will apply CSRF protection to all content pages that inherit from the Site.Master page.

The following requirements must be met for this solution to work:

All web forms making data modifications must use the Site.Master page. All requests making data modifications must use the ViewState. The web site must be free from all Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. See how to fix Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) using Microsoft .Net Web Protection Library for details. and also see [it](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf)

```
   public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
   {
   private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
   private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
   private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
//First, check for the existence of the Anti-XSS cookie
var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
Guid requestCookieGuidValue;

//If the CSRF cookie is found, parse the token from the cookie.
//Then, set the global page variable and view state user
//key. The global variable will be used to validate that it matches in the view state form field in the Page.PreLoad
//method.
if (requestCookie != null
&& Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
{
    //Set the global token variable so the cookie value can be
    //validated against the value in the view state form field in
    //the Page.PreLoad method.
    _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;

    //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
    //framework during each request
    Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
}
//If the CSRF cookie is not found, then this is a new session.
else
{
    //Generate a new Anti-XSRF token
    _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

    //Set the view state user key, which will be validated by the
    //framework during each request
    Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

    //Create the non-persistent CSRF cookie
    var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
    {
        //Set the HttpOnly property to prevent the cookie from
        //being accessed by client side script
        HttpOnly = true,

        //Add the Anti-XSRF token to the cookie value
        Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
    };

    //If we are using SSL, the cookie should be set to secure to
    //prevent it from being sent over HTTP connections
    if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL &&
    Request.IsSecureConnection)
    responseCookie.Secure = true;

    //Add the CSRF cookie to the response
    Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
}

    Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
}

protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //During the initial page load, add the Anti-XSRF token and user
    //name to the ViewState
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Set Anti-XSRF token
        ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;

        //If a user name is assigned, set the user name
        ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] =
        Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
    }
    //During all subsequent post backs to the page, the token value from
    //the cookie should be validated against the token in the view state
    //form field. Additionally user name should be compared to the
    //authenticated users name
    else
    {
        //Validate the Anti-XSRF token
        if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
        || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] !=
        (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
    {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of
    Anti-XSRF token failed.");
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to roll something basic, you can generate a Guid into a hidden field, then check you get the same one back, it's not as secure as a CAPTCHA, but would prevent random things posting to you without filling the form in, but wouldn't prevent scripts that do actually fill the form in and post from the page.

```
<asp:Hidden ID="Validation" runat="server" />
```

Page Load:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Validation.Text = guid.ToString();
Session["Token"] = guid;
```

Then on postback check you get the same one back...

---

Alternatively, take a look at the [Captcha NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Captcha/). It works on both webforms and MVC.

Show a Captcha:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="BotDetect" Namespace="BotDetect.Web.UI" 
  TagPrefix="BotDetect" %>

  […]

<BotDetect:Captcha ID="SampleCaptcha" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="CaptchaCodeTextBox" runat="server" />
```

Validate post:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    // validate the Captcha to check we're not dealing with a bot
    bool isHuman = SampleCaptcha.Validate(CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text);

    CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text = null; // clear previous user input

    if (!isHuman)
    {
      // TODO: Captcha validation failed, show error message  
    }
    else
    {
      // TODO: Captcha validation passed, proceed with protected action  
    }
}
```

Examples from the [documentation](https://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/asp.net-webforms-captcha-quickstart.html).